# Does Greedy Best First Search use a Queue or Stack?

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, queue, greedy

I'm just trying to implement the best first search and I am not sure if there are any LIFO or FIFO properties for this algorithm. If so which one should I use? Do I need to use it?

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: No actual implementation on the algorithm itself. I'm still thinking and researching about it which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search#Algorithm_.5B3.5D for this pseudocode:

```
OPEN = [initial state]
while OPEN is not empty or until a goal is found
do
 1. Remove the best node from OPEN, call it n.
 2. If n is the goal state, backtrace path to n (through recorded parents) and return path.
 3. Create n's successors.
 4. Evaluate each successor, add it to OPEN, and record its parent.
done
```

Step 1 says "remove the best node" - this implies the use of a [Priority Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Comment: Would a normal Queue suffice? For example Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>() ?

Comment: No, the key feature of the priority queue is that the "best" (as determined by a comparator) element is always in the front, regardless of order of insertion. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html -

Answer (score -2):

It uses a queue, so you should use FIFO.

Comment: It uses priority queue, so FIFO doesn't make much sense. The one that gets out first is the best element not the first inserted element  ;)